# Comparing fields between excel and access and fill

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

What i wanted to know is how do i get a vb application reading an excel file and a access database at same time, make them compare the fields and fill fields that are null.

for example:

Excel has this columns and fields:

Adress, postal code

avenue whatever no.30 ny, null(postal code doesnt have a value)

Access has this columns and fields:

Adress, postal code

avenue whatever no.30 ny, 2700-168

---

how do i make the access database fill the field in the excel file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to call the code from Excel in this instance. You could try something like this pseudocode example:

Sub foo()

```
 Dim db as DAO.Database
 Dim rs as Recordset
 Dim ws as Worksheet
 Dim i as Long

 Set db = Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("C:\MyPath\MyDatabase.mdb", ReadOnly:=True)
 Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Name of DB Table")
 Set ws = ActiveSheet

 i = 2
 ws.Range("A1") = "Address"
 ws.Range("B1") = "Postal Code"

 rs.MoveFirst
 Do While Not rs.EOF
      ws.Range("A" & i) = rs("Table Address Column Name")
      ws.Range("B" & i) = rs("Table Postal Code Column Name")
      rs.MoveNext
      i = i + 1
 Loop

 rs.close
 db.close

 Set db = Nothing
 Set rs = Nothing
 Set ws = Nothing
```

End Sub